# A weak cohomology theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

What  is  an example  of  a  functor  from the category  of  topological space to the category  of  groups  which  satisfy all conditions  of  cohomology theory  but  the  homotopy invariance  would be  reduced to the following  weaker  condition:

Two  homotopic maps  induce  conjugate  morphism(rather  than equal morphisms)

Comment: What does it mean for two morphisms of abelian groups to be conjugate?

Comment: @MikeMiller  I am sorry  for bad  formulation. I remove the  word abelian. Thank you.